# UI blocked when writing into textEdit

Tags: qt5

I've an application witch update execute commands on a database. I've a function witch execute that commands and in the in this function I display some messages to the user.

My problem is that the texts written into the textEdit are displayed at the end of the function work.

I've tried to use QThread but it does'nt resolve the problem

```
this->moveToThread(&threadText);
connect(&threadText, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(writeTexte()));
threadText.start();
```

Does anyone have an idea how to proceed to write into textEdit and not block the UI ?

Answer (score 0):

In **Qt** you *never need threads* in standard UI applications! That is because Qt uses something called *event loops* that process events smoothly without ever blocking. If you experience blocking, that is a sign that you have a bug somewhere in your code. For any beginner there are some pitfalls. The [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) on the subject is quite good.

It is hard to tell what your exact bug is because there is littel code to look at. I suggest you post more of your code, especially the naive approach that did not work before you added threads to the mix.

On a side note, using threads in Qt is of course possible and has it's usages, however it can be un-intuitive. I have found [this article](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) to be a really good starting point to understand how threads is used best in Qt.